# Kolmogorov-Smirnov two-sample test

Tags: kolmogorov-smirnov-test

The Suanshu Statistics Library supports the "Kolmogorov-Smirnov two-sample test" by rejecting the null hypothesis if $p$-value if smaller than significance level  $\alpha$ (e.g., $p<0.05$).

My question is whether there is any method to check if the "test statistic" exceeds the critical value (for $\alpha = 0.05$) to reject the "null hypothesis" in Suanshu Library or any other statistics library?. If not, is there any formula to compute the critical values by ourself for two-sample K-Smirnov test to check against test statistic.

Any suggestions regarding this are welcome.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I am assuming you are asking because the [Suanshu help page](http://www.numericalmethod.com/javadoc/suanshu/com/numericalmethod/suanshu/stats/test/distribution/kolmogorov/KolmogorovDistribution.html) reports in reference to the K-S distribution, "This is not done yet." Luckily, it is very easy to do in [R](http://www.r-project.org/%22R%22). If `x` and `y` are your two samples, `ks.test(x,y)` returns the test statistic and pvalue. For example,

```
> x <- rnorm(50)
> y <- runif(30)
> ks.test(x, y)    
        Two-sample Kolmogorov-Smirnov test    
data:  x and y 
D = 0.5, p-value = 9.065e-05
alternative hypothesis: two-sided
```

By default, it will compute exact or asymptotic p-values based on the product of the sample sizes (exact p-values for `n.x*n.y < 10000` in the two-sample case), or you can specify this option with a third argument, `exact=F` or `exact=T`. Exact p-values are calculated using the methods of [Marsaglia, et al. (2003)](http://www.jstatsoft.org/v08/i18/paper), which the Suanshu documentation also cites. Some large sample approximations are given [here](http://www.soest.hawaii.edu/wessel/courses/gg313/Critical_KS.pdf), although I don't have a proper citation. Lastly, if you don't want to install R, there are web calculators for the two-sample K-S test, although I don't know if they use the same algorithm as R because the one I found only reported three decimal points for the p-value.

Comment: @lockedoff.Your Explanation Helped me alot.                     As far as I know  all the Statistics Libraries uses P-Value to reject the Null Hypothesis,if p-value if smaller than significance level α (p<0.05/0.01)
                             (or)

Other option is to check if the "test statistic(D)" exceeds the critical value of α to reject the Null Hypothesis.

My confusion over this is,what is the appropriate one which give exact result if I want to reject the Null Hypothesis..

Thanks

Comment: @Sam Use either -- they give the same result (the relationship is 1-1 for fixed sample sizes and test size $\alpha$). Typically, you would report the test statistic and p-value, but not the critical value. E.g., "There was a statistically significant difference between the two distributions according to the two-sample Kolmogorov-Smirnov test (D = .6, p < .0001)." If $\alpha = .05$ is not an accepted convention in your field, report once that all of your statistical tests were of size $\alpha = .05$ (e.g., in your Methods section).

Answer (score 1):

SuanShu's Kolmogorov-Smirnov package can do anything R can do. The software computes both D, and p-values, just exactly in R. You can then use p-value to compare with whatever critical value threshold you want. In fact, SuanShu gives you the whole K-S distributions for different cases.

In addition, as pointed out in R's help page, R code does not handle duplicates. In this case, SuanShu is more precise in cases where there are duplicates.

See the examples here:

http://redmine.numericalmethod.com/projects/public/repository/entry/Examples/src/main/java/com/numericalmethod/suanshu/examples/HypothesisTesting.java

https://github.com/nmdev2020/SuanShu

https://nm.dev