# Calculating the Kolmogorov-Smirnov coefficient

Tags: hypothesis-testing, kolmogorov-smirnov-test

I need to calculate the coefficient of the Kolmogorov-Smirnov test for any given null hypothesis rejection level.

For example, have a look at the table [in this wikipedia entry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kolmogorov%E2%80%93Smirnov_test#Two-sample_Kolmogorov.E2.80.93Smirnov_test). It only gives $c(\alpha)$ for $\alpha=0.10, 0.05, 0.025, 0.01, 0.005, 0.001$. How can I calculate $c(\alpha)$ for a wider range of $\alpha$s?

If it is not trivial, can any one guide me on a place I can find a table for $c(\alpha)$ with larger $\alpha$ values?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Normally people use programs which can supply p-values. Note also that for small samples, those values in that table are only approximate. You may find this answer of some value: [*How do I find values not given in (/interpolate in) statistical tables?*](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/64538/how-do-i-find-values-not-given-in-interpolate-in-statistical-tables). Alternatively, [this](http://www.jstor.org/discover/10.2307/2236278) might be of some value.

Comment: Thank you very much for the references, I will definitely take a good look through them to learn more. I think I found my answer in the answer to this question: http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/13709/kolmogorov-smirnov-two-sample-test?rq=1 (Marsaglia, et al. (2003)). I read it and found a nice C code (that is the language I am working in) to give me the probability. It works fast and nice.

Comment: An alternative (and more easily accessible) link to the original paper should be [here](http://projecteuclid.org/DPubS?service=UI&version=1.0&verb=Display&handle=euclid.aoms/1177730256). Note that the tables given there are quite extensive. The $L(z)$ values correspond to $(1-\alpha)$ and the $z$ to $c(\alpha)$.

Answer (score 2):

I found [this paper](http://www.jstatsoft.org/v08/i18/paper)  (Marsaglia, et al. (2003)), that has a method to approximate the probability of obtaining a certain $D_n$ for a certain number of data. It Also has a `C` program that I used in my program and worked excellently.